# How to run maven command in a python script in Windows

Tags: python, windows, maven

How do I write a maven command in python? I saw this example online, but it doesn't seem to be working in Windows.

```
def local2(command, print_command=False):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    if print_command: print " ".join(command)
    output, errput = p.communicate()
    return p.returncode, output, errput

def uploadQAJavaToNexus():
    url = "example"
    groupId = "example"
    artifactId = "example"
    repositoryId = "example"
   # filePath =
    version = "version"

    status, stdout, stderr = local2([
                                     "mvn",
                                     "deploy:deploy-file",
                                     "-Durl=" +url,
                                     "-DrepositoryId=" +repositoryId,
                                     "-Dversion=" + version,
                                     "-Dfile=" + "path"
                                     "-DartifactId=" + artifactId,
                                     "-Dpackaging=" + "jar",
                                     "-DgroupId" + groupId,
                                     ])
    return status, stdout, stderr
```

UPDATE: This is the error I'm getting given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProject\src\Get.py", line 355, in <module>
    uploadQAJavaToNexus()
  File "C:\Get.py", line 250, in uploadQAJavaToNexus
    "-DgroupId" + groupId,
  File "C:\Get.py", line 227, in local2
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does nothing happen? Do you get any errors?

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified at  "-DgroupId" + groupId; & p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) @Jokab

Comment: It's clear that Windows can't find "mvn.exe". Use the fully-qualified path, or add its directory to `PATH`. You can set the latter temporarily in your script via `os.environ['PATH'] += ';%s' % mvn_directory`.

Comment: @eryksun When I try to run this mvn deploy:deploy-file command in the command line, I get the error as no plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project. What does this mean?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use fabric (http://www.fabfile.org/):

```
from fabric import local    
def maven_start():
    local('<cmd>')


$ fab maven_start
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate? local is given my undefined error